# How to Load data from AWS dynamo DB to Elasticsearch Using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-dynamodb

Hi i want to load data from AWS dynamo Db to elastic search on daily basis ,can it be done by logstash,if yes can you please provide the sample .conf file

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this:

> The Logstash plugin for Amazon DynamoDB gives you a nearly real-time view of the data in your DynamoDB table. The Logstash plugin for DynamoDB uses DynamoDB Streams to parse and output data as it is added to a DynamoDB table. After you install and activate the Logstash plugin for DynamoDB, it scans the data in the specified table, and then it starts consuming your updates using DynamoDB Streams and then outputs them to Elasticsearch, or a Logstash output of your choice.

https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-input-dynamodb